# Selectize render method is not called and my options are not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using selectize.js for remote search and get options against that search for my select input. 
I've seen example code in their demo

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#workers_paid').selectize({
            placeholder: "No worker Is selected",
            valueField: "name",
            labelfield : "name",
            searchField: 'name',
            render: {
                option: function (item,escape) {
                    console.log(item);
                }
            },
            onLoad : function (data) {
            }
            ,
            load: function (query, callback) {
                alert(query);
                let data = JSON.parse('{"users" : [{"user_name": "Humza"},{"user_name": "Humza"},{"user_name": "Humza"},{"user_name": "Humza"},{"user_name": "Humza"},{"user_name": "Humza"}]}');
                callback(data.users);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my code that i've written for loading a static data but still render is not logging any data in console .... Onload function is also working just render is not calling anything or any options is not being created. 
Sorry for bad english and thanks in advance